# How to download external file on gatsby site?

Tags: gatsby, netlify, cloudinary

I have a gatsby site deployed to Netlify with IPv6 enabled

For some reason when trying to download a file, it fails.

I have setup the following link

```
<a href="http://myexternafilelLink" download> Download</a>
```

The external link being a Cludinary url

http://res.cloudinary.com/clinic-plus/raw/upload/v1609936226/Man_Job_Spec_ClinicPlus_ysaoiz_1_z27rtq.xlsx

When I click this nothing happens, the only thing I see is the tab reload icon runing and then it stops and nothing happens.

I have confirmed the link works.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove your AdBlock (or whitelist the domain). I've tested it in a browser with both configurations and I can confirm that the links work. I also would suggest adding a `target="_blank"` property.

```
<a href="http://res.cloudinary.com/clinic-plus/raw/upload/v1609936226/Man_Job_Spec_ClinicPlus_ysaoiz_1_z27rtq.xlsx" target="_blank" download> Download</a>
```

Comment: Even if I disable it it still doesn't work

Comment: Even if: `<a href="http://res.cloudinary.com/clinic-plus/raw/upload/v1609936226/Man_Job_Spec_ClinicPlus_ysaoiz_1_z27rtq.xlsx" target="_blank" download> Download</a>` ?

Comment: It works on Firefox but doesn't work on chrome

Comment: What if you remove the download attribute?

Comment: Any updates? Faced with just the same problem on desktop chrome.

Comment: Feel free to open a new question with the required details, each scenario may be different. When I faced this issue it was related to AdBlock blocking requests

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have figured this out. The solution is simple. If you try to download file from this link via, e.g. via desktop chrome, then in the developer console you'll get this message

> Mixed Content: The site at 'https://stackoverflow.com/' was loaded over a secure connection, but the file at 'https://res.cloudinary.com/clinic-plus/raw/upload/v1609936226/Man_Job_Spec_ClinicPlus_ysaoiz_1_z27rtq.xlsx' was redirected through an insecure connection. This file should be served over HTTPS. This download has been blocked. See https://blog.chromium.org/2020/02/protecting-users-from-insecure.html for more details.

So, use `https` instead of `http`.

https://res.cloudinary.com/clinic-plus/raw/upload/v1609936226/Man_Job_Spec_ClinicPlus_ysaoiz_1_z27rtq.xlsx